# How to run a java code from command prompt which is using API?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, jar

I have written code that uses classes in jar files for Twitter4J API. I want to run my code through a command prompt. How would I do that? I tried:

```
$ javac -cp [path-to-twitter4j-jars] MyCode.java
```

It got compiled successfully, but when i run it by

```
$ java MyCode
```

But it does not find the Twitter4J classes. I am creating an instance of that class in my code.

Could anybody please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The classpath is where Java searches for actual `.class` files in fodlers by package.
Java does not look at JARs that are inside classpath folders.

You need to put the JAR file itself in the classpath; not the folder that contains it.

(alternatively, you can include `folder/*.jar` to put every JAR in that folder in the classpath)

Answer (score 2):

The JAR files still need to be on the classpath when *running* your application, not just when compiling.

Answer (score 2):

When running your Java application, the JVM needs to know about the jars also.

```
java -cp [path-to-twitter4j-jars] MyCode
```

Here's a [link to java command-line options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add jars to classpath:

```
java -cp .:path/to/twitter4j/jars MyCode
```

Docs:

```
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server,
              because you are running on a server-class machine.


-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you for helping me.                         `$ javac -cp [path-to-twitter4j-jars] MyCode.java                            $ java -cp .:[path-to-twitter4j-jars/myjar.jar] MyCode`